# Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE ntc_sales.AgentAmounts; expected 1, got 0

Tags: entity-framework

Here i am  tring to call the stored procedure with paramter using entityframework 
it's get the error:Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE ntc_sales.AgentAmounts; expected 1, got 0
Below code

```
`enter code here`[HttpGet]
    public virtual List<AgentAmounts> AgentAmountbyId(int id)
    {
      string SQLQuery = @"call AgentAmounts();";
      var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
      //List<object> listobj = new List<object>();
      List<AgentAmounts> data = objectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<AgentAmounts>(SQLQuery, 
     id).AsQueryable().ToList();
     return data;
    }
```

Comment: Error seems pretty clear to me. You're not passing an expected parameter to the AgentAmounts procedure. Since you have not provided the code for AgentAmounts nobody will be able to know for sure.

Comment: yes Dismissile i found that it's working fine now

Answer (score 2):

```
public virtual List<AgentAmounts> AgentAmountbyId(int id)
{
  string SQLQuery = @"call AgentAmounts(@vagent);";
  var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
  //List<object> listobj = new List<object>();
  List<AgentAmounts> data = objectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<AgentAmounts>(SQLQuery,new Mysqlparamter("@vagent",id).AsQueryable().ToList();
 return data;
}
```